# In Trajan, can a player get a bonus tile with zero votes on the senate track?

Tags: trajan

In Trajan, if nobody advances on the Senate, do the top two discs get the bonus tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

From the [Rulebook](http://passportgamestudios.com/pgs/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Trajan_Rules.pdf), page 9:

> Ties are broken in favor of the player with the higher
>   position on the senate track, in case of the same position
>   in favor of that player whose disc is higher up in the
>   stack.

So, if all discs are still at the starting point, the order of discs on the stack matters for determining Consul and Vice-Consul.